Expo 52: Android Build Failed After Adding React Native Google Cast
My android build was working flawlessly until I installed react-native-google-cast.
Here's the error I'm getting (on npx expo run:android):

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
[com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0] C:\Users\19147\.gradle\caches\8.10.2\transforms\ffdf14fbea66d702727e81cea65b023c\transformed\animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
        Namespace 'android.support.graphics.drawable' is used in multiple modules and/or libraries: com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0, com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0. Please ensure that all modules and libraries have a unique namespace. For more information, See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
[androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1] C:\Users\19147\.gradle\caches\8.10.2\transforms\3828a1355f94679380df745e783177a3\transformed\versionedparcelable-1.1.1\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
        Namespace 'androidx.versionedparcelable' is used in multiple modules and/or libraries: androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1, com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0. Please ensure that all modules and libraries have a unique namespace. For more information, See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
C:\Users\19147\Documents\vmios\vmios\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:28:18-86 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.13.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:18-86
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-162 to override.

See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 7s
164 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 158 up-to-date
Error: C:\Users\19147\Documents\vmios\vmios\android\gradlew.bat app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a exited with non-zero code: 1

What I did:
yarn add react-native-google-cast

Added to app.json plugins:
  [
    "react-native-google-cast",
    {
      "receiverAppId": "4447E828",
      "iosStartDiscoveryAfterFirstTapOnCastButton": false
    }
  ],
  ["expo-build-properties", { "ios": { "deploymentTarget": "16.0" } }]

Note my setup is working fine on my eas ios dev build.

Might be relevant
